# Json Mapping With Numbers as Property Names

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping, transformation

I have the following json as an example:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "amount": "1"
        },
        "2": {
            "amount": "98"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no control over the incoming JSON structure.  I have been trying to find a way to map these to a DTO using JSONProperties, however I can't declare a property using a number.

Also I have tried iterating thought the JSON using JSONObject but I can't seem to get it to go through all child nodes, just the top level.

```
JSONObject payload = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject newPayload = payload;

Iterator<String> keys = payload.keys();

while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();

                if (StringUtils.isNumber(key)) {
                    newPayload.put("element" + key, payload.get(key));
                    newPayload.remove(key);
                }
}
```

Has anyone come across a similar situation and found a solution.

All this to eventually have the JSON transformered into XML...
Inherited this platform, no time for refactoring lol, not my choice.

Comment: _Technically_ speaking, these aren't numbers; they're strings of digits. Whether you can or should treat them as numbers depends on what you know about the contract of the service.

Comment: I should have said the final part of this, the final outcome of this needs to be transformed into XML, hence the need to get rid of the number for a key name. I'll edit the question

Comment: Are the numbers supposed to be sequential indices, 1-based?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes, have been told it should always be 2 indices, but I'm dealing with a very unreliable responses, so trying to cover possibilities.   I have a solution, .replace(), but that's gross and I'm at the point of curiosity now.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions, but assuming that you need only to *deserialize* this pathological structure, here's how I'd handle it (Groovy-style for compactness):

```
class ResponseData {
  Map<String, Long> amounts = new HashMap<>()  // or different key type


  static class WrappedAmount {
    String amount

    Long getAmountAsLong() {
      return Long.valueOf(amount)
    }
  }


  @JsonAnySetter  // this is the magic step
  void appendAmount(String key, WrappedAmount amount) {
    amounts.put(key, amount.getAmountAsLong())
  }
}


class Response {
  boolean success  // REST endpoints should use status codes, not properties
  ResponseData data
}
```

This will *deserialize* the response you have into a data structure that's manageable. If, as you suggested, these keys are indices and will be removed and replaced with something like an ordering of XML tags, you might want to replace `HashMap` with `TreeMap` so that you can just iterate over it to produce your output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonProperty` annotation and specify name.

```
@JsonProperty("1")
private String one;
```

Comment: This is true for the specific JSON presented, but OP gives the impression that the result set is arbitrary.

Comment: This is an option, but i would like to be able to handle an arbitrary result set as I don't trust the JSON to not have a dynamically built schema, I've already lectured about the use of arrays

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming `JSON` structure is unknown, we can use recursion to parse the entire `JSON` (including the child nodes).

The below code will traverse the entire `JSON` and store it in a `Map<String, Object>`. We can whatever we want (like mapping the values to a DTO) either during the recursion itself, or we can again recursively traverse the `Map<String, Object>`.

```java
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

private static Map<String, Object> parseMap(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> keySet = jsonObject.keySet();
    for (String key : keySet) {
        Object value = jsonObject.get(key);

        if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = parseList((JSONArray) value);
        } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = parseMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        // We can do whatever we want with a value of a key here.
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}

private static List<Object> parseList(JSONArray array) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object value : array) {
        if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = parseList((JSONArray) value);
        } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = parseMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        // We can do whatever we want with an element of a JSON list here.
        list.add(value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Driver code :-

```java
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);

Map<String, Object> map = parseMap(jsonObject);
System.out.println("Resulting Map = " + map);
```